# Where is my TWRP backups on encrypted Android?

Tags: backup, encryption, cyanogenmod, twrp

I encrypted my Android tablet which is a nexus 7. After that I did couple backups. Today I wanted to see the size of the total backups  so I open the TWRP folder on my sdcard. There is nothing there. I do not see them anywhere else either.

I made backups before encrypting my device. and TWRP backups always resided in the TWRP on the sdcard.

So where are the TWRP backups  after I encryted my device (via standard android enc).

I am using TWRP Cyanogenmod11 Android 4.4.4 , using a recent build from this month.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Older versions of TWRP do not have the ability to mount encrypted file systems, so therefore, it cannot make backups.  In addition, TWRP only supports decrypting certain devices.  According to the [TWRP2 Project Page](http://teamw.in/project/twrp2), the only devices that they *explicitly* define as having decryption support are Galaxy Nexus and TouchWiz devices.

Comment: Well, I think it does recognize the enc filesystems. Because when I run recovery it asks me the password first. And then it does not complain about anything during the backup/

Comment: Right, it does do that. But the backups are known to just be an empty process when encrypted - literally nothing happens. Give me a minute and I'll update my answer with documentation.

Comment: Also this says that it does. http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?s=92f28f7245a7929328b02707803084a0&p=52348025&postcount=3

Comment: See my edit.  Also, if you read that entire thread, the people that are asking are not able to make backups either...

Comment: so what do you think my options are then for backing up the whole system that has encfs ?

Comment: AFAIK, backups simply don't work with encrypted partitions.  I hope I'm wrong and someone can help!

Comment: Ok I understand your point. The other thing is that I was able to upgrade my system while it was encrypted with with TWRP. Would not that mean that my version of TWRP works already with encfs?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I don't understand. Other users are reporting that they're able to flash zips. Honestly, I don't have an explanation for that, other than its some sort of bug.